# Bringing in a CSV file from online (Google Spreadsheet) into a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, google-sheets

So I have a google spreadsheet ( https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Agymc2_-gI59dGxvRnZoRzNuNENIUE9kZ0h6WExxSXc&usp=sharing ) that has my golf scores from each round that I have golfed. I want to bring that spreadsheet into my javascript file and put it into an array, so that I can manipulate it and put it into tables and such. Google Docs has a CSV file url that will automatically send in the newest spreadsheet into that link, so I figured that would be the easiest way. Would anyone be able to write up some quick code to take this cdv file location ( https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Agymc2_-gI59dGxvRnZoRzNuNENIUE9kZ0h6WExxSXc&output=csv ) and bring it into a javascript array using javascript? Thank you so much!
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

[csonv.js](https://github.com/archan937/csonv.js) is the library you are looking for, followed by jQuery's [parseJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) call.

Comment: That would work but unfortunately that library wants the format to be: the id in the first row, then the kind of value (string, int, ext) then the value and google docs csv does not submit it that way :( is there anyway I can change that csonv.js file to not need the kind of value?

Comment: a quick google searched revealed a function in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sturtevant/AZFvQ/).Hope that helps.